# Regular expression - Get specific part of string

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence:

> b.g The big bag of bits was bugged.

How can I exclude the **b.g** from it by using a regular expression?

I am sure I need a negative lookahead but I cannot get it right yet.
Something like

```
^(?!b\.g)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to match, please be more specific.

Comment: Also, there's more than one regex syntax, engine, etc. We need to know which one you need an answer for, and what you *actually* want to match (the largest concatenated string of words that dosen't contain `b.g`?)

Comment: The regular expression will help you to match that string but you need to use an specific function/method or tool to apply the replacement you want as you can check here: https://regexr.com/3gvbq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
[^\S].*
```

What `[^\S]` does is basically skip any character until it reaches the first space. then start capturing. No need in this case for negative or positing Lookbehind.

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wlNHPW/1/)

If you prefer to do it with positive Lookbehind, you can do it this way

```
(?<=b\.g).*
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wlNHPW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/^...//'` strips the first 3 characters, "b.g", but I doubt that's what you're really asking. Your `^` anchor appears to be a red herring.

You already have correct escaping for `.` period, just stick with that:

```
sed 's/b\.g//'
```

Python's [positive lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-syntax) `?<=` may be what you are trying to find words to express:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=b\.g)(.*)', 'b.g The big bag of bits was bugged.')
>>> print(m.group(1))
 The big bag of bits was bugged.
```

Comment: I'm not clear that the OP is trying to find an operation to *remove* that string (which isn't something that standardized regex syntax offers at all, hence the need to use other commands `sed` provides), vs a way to match everything in their input *except* that word.

Answer (score 0):

In python you could do something like this:

```
import re
w = 'b.g The big bag of bits was bugged.'
print w

d = re.compile(r'^b.g\s')
a = re.sub(d, '', w)
print a
```